# Vector bundles in $\text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to find all vector bundles $E$ on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ for which there is the exact sequence
\begin{equation}0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)\stackrel{\alpha} \to E\stackrel{\beta}\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)\to0.\,\,\,\,(1)\end{equation}
We have that the rank of $E$ is equal to 2 and by Grothendieck's splitting $E\cong\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-a)\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a)$, where $a$ is non-negative integer. Here I stucked. How could I find all possible values of $a$?

$\textbf{Update}$

Here is my try.
Suppose that $a>2$. Then $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-a)\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a))=\text{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-a)\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a), \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2))=H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a+2)).$ Thus
$$\alpha=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
f\\
\end{array}
\right), \,\,\,\beta=(g\,\,0),$$
where $f,g\in H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a+2))$.

But it seems that $(1)$ is still exact.

$\textbf{Second update}$

I guess that the reason is that there exists no surjection $g:\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-a)\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)$. Equivalently, there is no surjection $h:\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(d)$ for $d>0$ because otherwise every section of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(d)$ would be of the form $h\cdot r$, where $r$ is a section of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ and $h$ a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$, and this is obviously not true.

Is it okay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume $a\geq 0$ without loss of generality. Then, the map from $\mathcal{O}(a)\to\mathcal{O}(2)$ can not be zero, since if it were, then $\mathcal{O}(a)$ will inject into $\mathcal{O}(-2)$, which is absurd. Thus, we get $a\leq 2$. All these are possible and can easily be checked. That is $a=0,1,2$.

Comment: I do not understand the argument "Then, the map from $\mathcal{O}(a)\to\mathcal{O}(2)$ can not be zero, since if it were, then $\mathcal{O}(a)$ will inject into $\mathcal{O}(−2)$, which is absurd". If the map $\mathcal{O}(a)\to\mathcal{O}(2)$ is zero, then the short exact sequence gives that we have a surjection $\mathcal{O}(-a)\to\mathcal{O}(2)$, which after dualisation gives an injection $\mathcal{O}(-2)\to\mathcal{O}(a)$. Where is the contradiction?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}(a)$ injects into $\mathcal{O}(a)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-a)$ and if the composite from $\mathcal{O}(a)\to \mathcal{O}(2)$ is zero, it must factor through $\mathcal{O}(-2)$. Can $\mathcal{O}(-a)\to\mathcal{O}(2)$ surjective? If it were it has to be an isomorphism since both areline bundles on an irreducible variety, and $-a\leq 0, 2>0$.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. In the case $a=1$, how to construct the map $\mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(1)\to\mathcal{O}(2)$? My guess is that there are two possibilities: $$\mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(1)\stackrel{(z_0^3\,\,z_1)} \to\mathcal{O}(2)$$ and $$\mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(1)\stackrel{(z_1^3\,\,z_0)} \to\mathcal{O}(2),$$ where $(z_0:z_1)$ are local coordinates.

Comment: A map from $\mathcal{O}(a)\to\mathcal{O}(b)$ is given by multiplication by a form of degree $b-a$ (and thus if $b-a<0$, it has to be zero). So, in the above, the map is given by a pair $(p,q)$ where $p$ is a form of degree 3 and $q$ is a form of degree 1. Surjectivity says that these forms must not have a common zero on the projective line and any such pair gives the required map.