# Extension of vector bundles on $\mathbb{CP}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $\lambda\in\text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2))$ and $E_\lambda$ be a vector bundle on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ which is given by the exact sequence
\begin{equation}0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)\to E_\lambda\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)\to0,\,\,\,\,(1)\end{equation}
and corresponds to $\lambda$.

Then, as it was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529355/vector-bundles-in-textext1-mathcalo-mathbbp12-mathcalo-math), $E\cong\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a_\lambda)\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-a_\lambda)$ for some $a_\lambda\in\{0,1,2\}$.

For each $\lambda$ I want to find the explicit value of $a_\lambda$. Can anyone help me?

I tried the following explicit construction.

Let $P=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)^{\oplus4}$. There is the surjective map $P\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)$, which is given by the evaluation map $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(3))\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(3)$ twisted by $-1$. Let $F=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)^{\oplus3}$ be the kernel of this map so we have the exact sequence
\begin{equation}0\to F\to P\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)\to0.\,\,\,\,(2)\end{equation}
Note that $\text{Ext}^1(P,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2))=0$. Thus applying $\text{Hom}(-,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2))$ to $(2)$ we obtain the surjective connecting map
$$\delta:\text{Hom}(F,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2))\to\text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)).$$
Now from the surjectivity of $\delta$ there exists $f\in\text{Hom}(F,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2))$ such that $\delta(f)=\lambda$ and $E_\lambda$ is given as the push-out of $F\to P$ and $F\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)$.

I don't know how to compute $f$ explicitly for a given $\lambda$ and then how to compute the push-out.

Maybe there exists a different approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can use duality (Hartshorne, III Thm 7.1),

$$ \mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)) \simeq \mathrm{H}^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2))^{\vee} $$

Identify $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2) = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-p -q)$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct points. Let $A_{\lambda}$ be a homogeneous quadratic polynomial corresponding to $\lambda$.

You can use $p$, $q$ and $A_{\lambda}$ to construct $E_{\lambda}$.

If $A_{\lambda}(p)=A_{\lambda}(q)=0$, then $a_{\lambda}=0$.

If $A_{\lambda}(p)=0 $ and $A_{\lambda}(q)\neq 0$, then $a_{\lambda}=1$.

If $A_{\lambda}(p\neq 0 $ and $A_{\lambda}(q)\neq 0$, then $a_{\lambda}=2$.

Note that choosing $p$ and $q$ is the same as choosing a basis for $\mathrm{H}^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1))$, which determines a basis for $\mathrm{H}^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2))$ that you have to fix to construct a isomorphism
$$ \mathrm{H}^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)) \simeq \mathrm{H}^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2))^{\vee} $$

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? Namely, why if  $A_{\lambda}(p)=0 $ and $A_{\lambda}(q)\neq 0$, then $a_{\lambda}=1$?

Comment: Working out the details I found easier to use ${\rm H}^1(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-4))$ instead of ${\rm H}^0(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2))$. Both are easy to describe but the first gives explicitly the cocycle for $E$. I'll edit my answer asap...

Comment: Okay, I will wait.

Comment: Could you please explain your solution?

Comment: Take a look at this construction: https://deltaepsilons.wordpress.com/2015/01/26/extensions-of-line-bundles-on-the-projective-line/

Comment: Thank you. There are lots of typos in that notes but I will try to understand the computation. Also the computation is given for the elements of the basis only, not for an arbitrary vector.

Comment: For an arbitrary everything goes fine until the part that you have to diagonalize the transition matrix. I think this has to be done case by case or there's a fancy algebraic manipulation that I didn't get yet...

Comment: And about the typos, just write down the Cech complex with the standard covering and restrict both sequences to one of the affine charts. From the definition of the pullback you'll get the right directions.