# Short exact sequence on $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, exact-sequence

Let F be a torsion free sheaf of rank $n+4$ over $\mathbb{P}^1$ which fits in the SES

$0\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^1}(-3)^{n+2}\longrightarrow F\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)^2\longrightarrow0$

> Is $F\simeq\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-3)^n\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)^4$?

The reason for this guess is the Koszul SES

$0\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-3)\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)^2\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)\longrightarrow 0$

Comment: Question: Is computing $Ext^1_O (O(-3), O(-1))$ (in the category of coherent sheaves on $P^1$) possible?

Comment: @AreaMan: nice idea! However, it is $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal O(-1),\mathcal O(-3))$ that we need. We can consider $\operatorname{Ext}$ in coherent sheaves or $\mathcal O$-modules; it doesn't matter. A simple computation (see Hartshorne Prop. III.6.7 and Prop. III.6.3(c)) shows that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal O(-1),\mathcal O(-3)) = \operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal O,\mathcal O(-2)) = H^1(\mathbb P^1, \mathcal O(-2))$, which is one-dimensional by Serre-duality (as $\omega_{\mathbb P^1} = \mathcal O(-2)$). Therefore, no luck (especially once we introduce big direct sums).

Comment: Do you mean $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^1}(-3)^n \oplus \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^1}(-2)^4$? Then I think the answer is *sometimes*.  There are other possibilities, e.g. $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^1}(-3)^{n+2} \oplus \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^1}(-1)^2$ and $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^1}(-3)^{n+1} \oplus \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^1}(-2)^2 \oplus \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^1}(-1).$

Comment: And to the OP: we cannot answer your question if you don't tell us what the maps are. There are many extensions of $\mathcal O(-1)^2$ by $\mathcal O(-3)^{n+2}$, as my previous comment shows.

Comment: @Remy, I have a similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601588/extension-of-vector-bundles-on-mathbbcp1. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Thank you very much! I just realized in my problem, I was working with the extra requirement that $F$ must inject into some $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)^k$. Hence the choice $F\simeq \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-3)^n\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)^4$ is obvious. I'm really sorry!